# is English function not able to apply row wise in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am adding a function which will check whether the text value in the column is English or not. I am adding a column for True or False. I want to check row wise whether the value column from the table is English or not. I have tried multiple ways but I am getting error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isascii'

```
def isEnglish(s):
    return s.isascii()  

ic1 = sqlalchemy.text(f"select * from  public.table")
res_ic1 = pd.read_sql(ic1, conn)
df_ic1 = pd.DataFrame(res_ic1)
print(df_ic1)
print(df_ic1.columns.tolist())
df_ic1["eng_check"] = ""
#df_ic1["eng_check"] = df_ic1["eng_check"].apply(isEnglish(df_ic1["value"]))
#df_ic1["eng_check"] = df_ic1.apply(isEnglish(df_ic1["value"]))
#df_ic1["eng_check"] = df_ic1.apply(lambda row : isEnglish(["value"]))
#df_ic1["eng_check"] = df_ic1["eng_check"].apply(isEnglish("value"))
df_ic1 = df_ic1.assign(eng_check=lambda row: isEnglish(row["value"]))
```

[Code Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtqLN.jpg)

Comment: English words like `naïve` would fail that test. Never mind English names like `Charlotte Brontë`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What I am missing in applying the function? Any idea ? The code is giving error

Comment: The error is clear, but your intention is *not*. A Series object isn't a string. What are you looking for? `isascii` wouldn't help even with normal strings

Comment: The opposite also doesn't hold true. Many sentences in many non-English languages can be expressed in ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Use `df['TextField'].str.match(r'^[\u0000-\u007F]*$')` instead.

First of all, English uses more characters than those in the 7-bit ASCII range. That test would fail for words like `naïve` or English names like `Charlotte Brontë`. *No* system uses just the limited ASCII range anyway.

Second, the error is correct. The *Series* object has no string operations. [String operations on Series values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html#string-handling) are accessed through `Series.str`, eg :

```
df['is_upper']=df['TextField'].str.isupper()
```

There's no `isascii` because it's not really useful in data processing. Python strings are Unicode and *no* system uses just the 7-bit ASCII range. Usually, when people talk about ASCII they mean the Latin 1/ISO-8859-1 encoding. All

You could use [str.match](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) to check if a text field matches a certain pattern.

```
df['is_Latin1']=df['TextField'].str.match(r'^[\u0000-\u007F]*$')
```

The pattern `^[\u0000-\u007F]*$` matches strings that only contain characters in the Latin 1 range, from start `^` to end `$`.

That includes unprintable characters like NULL and BELL, which are valid ASCII characters but never appear in text data. A better pattern may be `^\w*$`, which matches all word characters